# Trouble binding to ApplicationController inside nested view in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

So here is what I have:

```
App

   TopbarView

   UserIndexController

      UserRowView
```

That is the nesting that happens.

from inside the TopbarView I can access the ApplicationController.

But inside the UserRowView I can't seem to access it.

How can I access something on the ApplicationController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `needs: ['application']` to your `UserIndexController` and you can access it on the `controllers.application` property.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have {{#if controller.controllers.application.isAuthenticated }} and similar code in my app. It does work, but doesn't seem pretty. Is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: You could have either a mixin or a common base class for controllers that have the need for that behaviour, and set up either a binding or an computed property alias (isAuthenticated: `Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.isAuthenticated')`). That'll clean your templates up significantly and make Demeter a bit happier.